# How to use mongoexport with query containing binary data (like UUID)

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I just had an annoying problem. I wanted to use mongoexport, with a query containing binary data and couldn't bring it to work.

You may reproduce it by creating a collection which contains a UUID Field.

The following should work but doesn't (returning 'FailedToParse: Argument of $type in $bindata object must be a hex string representation of a single byte'):

```
mongoexport --db test --collection collec --query '{"uuid": { "$binary": "zaHKuGOpQqOxf3tkCofZjw==", "$type": "3"}}'
```

I also tried this one, using the shell BSON type, it doesn't work either (returning 'FailedToParse: "new" keyword not followed by Date constructor'):

```
mongoexport --db test --collection collec --query '{"uuid": { new BinData(3, "zaHKuGOpQqOxf3tkCofZjw==")}'
```

And neither does this one (inspired from mongoexport doc 2.4, returning 'FailedToParse: Expecting quoted string'):

```
mongoexport --db test --collection collec --query "{uuid: { \$binary: 'zaHKuGOpQqOxf3tkCofZjw==', \$type: 3}}"
```

Any hint ? Could it be a bug ? My version of mongo is 2.4.6. I ended up querying and printing from Django and mongoengine :-/

Comment: I answered almost the same question yesterday, but that question was targeted at mongodump, not mongoexport. I still think this can be considered a duplicate because I could practically copy paste my answer, which I don't want to do.

Comment: except that escaping doesn't seem to work here !

Comment: Well, it works on my machine (TM). Make sure the escaping is precisely correct. My string was: `"{\"_id\" : { \"$binary\" : \"zaHKuGOpQqOxf3tkCofZjw==\", \"$type\" : \"03\" } }"`. Don't use single quotes, but backslash-escaped. Also make sure `$type` is `"03"`, not `3`, not `03` and not `"3"`. Well, argh, wait, seems you're on linux, right?

Comment: thanks for the hint with "03", it is now valid, but it is exporting no records whereas the find on the shell returns some

Comment: but the 03 hint was precious, it allows to answer the question without all double-quotes and this works !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it works finally, when using the type as a hex value (meaning 03 instead of 3), and no escaping required:

```
mongoexport --db test --collection collec --query '{"uuid": { "$binary": "zaHKuGOpQqOxf3tkCofZjw==", "$type": "03"}
```